# Why I can not start my tomcat from command line?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, tomcat7

I downloaded tomcat version 7.0.16 binary distributions core tar.gz from tomcat's official website to my ubuntu machine, then extracted the downloaded file.

Then, I used terminal command to specify the path to `~/apache-tomcat-7.0.16/bin`$ , then I entered `startup` command, but I have got '**startup: command not found**' message, but when I used linux command `ls`, there were ***startup.bat*** and ***startup.sh*** under *bin/*.

I also tried to enter startup.bat and startup.sh, the same message returned. Why I can not start my tomcat v7 from ubuntu terminal window??

Comment: .bat files only work on Windows boxes.  .sh are *nix shell scripts which should work.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're trying to run `startup.sh` from the directory that contains it, you'll need to prefix the name with `./` - the current directory is not on the `PATH` by default. Also, you'll need the `.sh` extension.

So either:

```
~/apache-tomcat-7/bin$ ./startup.sh
```

Or:

```
~/apache-tomcat-7$ bin/startup.sh
```

Comment: I tried your command, I got message: Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/john/apache-tomcat-7.0.16
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/john/apache-tomcat-7.0.16
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/john/apache-tomcat-7.0.16/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/john/apache-tomcat-7.0.16/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/john/apache-tomcat-7.0.16/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

Comment: That command returns after writing out the status information you displayed, the server is running as a daemon process in the background. You can test it by hitting `http://localhost:8080`

Answer (score 7):

you should like this:

sudo chmod +x /Users/yw/Tomcat/bin/*.sh

Answer (score 6):

Actually the problem is your `startup.sh` does not have the execute permission that is why you are unable to start it. First check that properly, type `./startup.sh` there and observe what it says. If it is saying that "you don't have the permission" then give it execute permission by this command `chmod 777 startup.sh`. Then try to to start it.

Answer (score 3):

I did it with command:

```
chmod +x catalina.sh
sudo ./startup.sh
```